# selectionsort recursion code with execution killed(fragmentation error)

Tags: c++, selection-sort

I believe my code is right, it even matches my scheme that I drew before I implemented it but I am getting execution killed, similar to fragmentation error, but I do not think I am going out of bound logically I am in bound. I am starting from the left of the array pushing towards the end of array as I put the smallest one in the staring point of each loop of recursion

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void print(int* arr, int size);
void selectionsort(int i,int size, int *arr);
void selectionsort(int i,int size, int *arr)
    {
        int smallestindex=i;
        int smallest=arr[i];
        for (int j=i;j<size;j++)
        {
            if(smallest>arr[j])
            {smallestindex=j;}
        }
        int temp=arr[smallestindex];
                arr[smallestindex]=arr[i];
                arr[i]=temp;
        if(i<size)
        {
           selectionsort(i++,size,arr);
        }
    }

    int main() {
        int array[]={6,5,4,3,2,1};
        int size=6;
        int init=0;
        selectionsort(init,size, array);
        print(array,6);
      }
    void print(int* arr, int size)
    {
        cout<<"Now the array will be printed"<<endl;
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your recursion call..
use pre increment. 
i.e 
 selectionsort(++i,size,arr); // note that i++ replaced with ++i

Comment: but I changed my recursive call statement to if(i<size-1) so hopefully i wont need pre increment

Comment: I suggested pre increment not as a solution  for size problem..
You need to increment i before next function call. 
Suppose you called function selectionsort(0,6,array), next desired recursive call is selectionsort(1,6,array) inorder to ignore already sorted first element. But the call you get is selectionsort(0,6,array) itself.
You need to increment i before the call is made. So use  ++i not  i++.
Hope it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are stopping the recursion at the end of the function. You are increasing the value of i in the function call, then use it and only at the end you are checking if it is bigger than size.
In the final iteration when you are calling selectionsort with i++ i equals size. Then you are running int smallest=arr[i] and get array out of bounds.
you need to check that i is smaller than size in the first line of the function and return if not.

Comment: hi thanks so much I have changes if(i<size-1), and I am still getting time limit exceeded error

Comment: is the first line of the function:
 if (i >= size) {return;}

Comment: you have other bugs BTW, like not updating smallest when you find a smaller number

Comment: hi sorry I did not understand your first question do you want me to have  base case where the recursion would stop calling itself, that's how it seems like to me.

Comment: also about upating smaller, I am updating the smallest index if any smaller number is found, else I am not that way the element of current index remains if its smallest of current selectionsort, else element of current index and smallest index gets swapped.